# C++ CreateProcess fail receiving path from socket on Windows 7 (64)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, createprocess

I'm trying to make a simple application controller using CreateProcess() function. The program receives te path of the program who will be executed by a socket and store it in to a char[] variable, later it sends the variable to a function who will execute it.

The error i'm getting is

```
Client: Received data is: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
Server: Bytes received: 30.
CreateProcess failed (123).
```

(2) = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I tryed with doble slash (//) and i receive error (123)

```
Client: Received data is: C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe
Server: Bytes received: 33.
CreateProcess failed (123).
```

(123) = ERROR_INVALID_NAME

The function who receive the path of program to execute:

```
bytesRecv = recv(m_socket, recvbuf, 200, 0);

if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
   printf("Server: recv() error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
else
{
   printf("\nClient: Received data is: %s\n", recvbuf);
   printf("Server: Bytes received: %ld.\n", bytesRecv );
   NewProcess(1,LPWSTR(recvbuf)); // <---- Call to NewProcess function with path
}
```

and the function who start the process:

```
void NewProcess(int count,LPWSTR cmd)
{
    LPTSTR concatenation = _T(" ");
    LPTSTR cmdArgs = NULL;


    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    // Start the child process. 

    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,       // Program full path
    cmd,                    // Arguments
    NULL,                       // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,                       // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,                      // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,                          // No creation flags
    NULL,                       // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,                       // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,                        // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )                       // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    printf("\nProcess ID: %d Terminated!",pi.dwProcessId);

    // Close process and thread handles.

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong, i supose is something about variable types, but i can't find the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do debug output of 'cmd' param before calling CreateProcess(), it could be broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
LPWSTR(recvbuf)
```

You have cast the buffer to be a pointer to a wide character array, but it is not. We can tell that because just before you wrote:

```
printf("\nClient: Received data is: %s\n", recvbuf);
```

This means that `recvbuf` is a pointer to an 8 bit ANSI character array. Either use `CreateProcessA`, or convert from ANSI to UTF-16.

The lesson you should take away from this is that every time you cast a character array you are quite likely getting it wrong. The compiler presumably objected to you passing `recvbuf` because it correctly determined that `recvbuf` was in the wrong format. By casting you are simply suppressing the compiler and lying to it. Your cast does not make `recvbuf` be an `LPWSTR`. It is still `LPSTR`, but you've told the compiler to ignore that error.

You will need to be sure that `recvbuf` is null-terminated. If there is a transmission failure, and `recvbuf` is not null-terminated, then you have a buffer overrun condition.

Finally, escaping backslashes is something that you do in source code only.

Comment: Thanks! i used CreateProcessA and recvbuf wasn't null-terminated. I added `recvbuf[bytesRecv - 2] = '\0';` to eliminate the `\n` received from keyboard input and add the correct null character at the end of string before send it to CreateProcess function. It  works fine now. Thanks again ;)